# Handle http delete

Tags: angular, error-handling, observable

I have a REST service where I can delete a resource by `id`. In case of *success* I get `200` without a response object. In case of *error* I get `404` with response object containing the error message.

Here is the service code:

```
deleteResource(id: number, cascade: boolean) {
    let url = this.url + '/' + id;
    if (cascade) url = url + '?cascade=true';

    return this.http.delete(url)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Here also is the handleError function:

```
private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let body: ErrorMessage;
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      try {
        body = error.json();
        console.log(body);
      } catch (e) {
        // No content response..
        body = null;
      }
    }
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    //console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(body || errMsg);
  }
```

I am using this code as follows in my component.

```
this.resourceService.deleteResource(resource.resource_id, cascade).subscribe(
  res=>{
      console.log('This is never executed'+ res);
  },
  err=>{
    console.log('This is always executed' + err);
  }
);
```

Whenever I execute the code above, always the `err` section is executed despite the response status. Can someone explain why? What is the proper way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about Angular promise model but maybe the error be thrown by `res.Json()` (cause response object is null) and then caught by internal pipe?

Comment: Hello Brumiano, thanks for  the hint actually you are right, I am getting it due to res.json().

Answer (score 0):

Since, I get a response in some cases. I had to add check the response if it is defined or not and then process it.